# input custom text in youtube text field using selenium python

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, beautifulsoup, selenium-ide

I'm making a text scraper for youtube in which I want to enter data and search videos and collect data of it. I'm facing problems in entering data in the text field. Can anyone suggest me a method to do that?

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup 

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml') #Use the page as source

page = driver.get('https://freight.rivigo.com/dashboard/home')

import sys

from importlib import reload
reload


elem = driver.find_element_by_tag_name("body")

no_of_pagedowns = 120

while no_of_pagedowns:
    elem.send_keys(Keys.PAGE_DOWN)
    time.sleep(0.5)
    no_of_pagedowns-=1

soup = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'lxml')
```

In between this code I want to add a custom text in input field, lets say "comedy" and want to get data on that. I'm stuck on how to input data and I'm quite new to this so any sort of help will be helpful.

Comment: Why don't you try the Youtube API? Here's the link for the [Github Repo](https://github.com/youtube/api-samples/tree/master/python). This repo will allow you to understand most of the functionalities provided by the API and their usage in Python.

Comment: @Argon I'm trying to make the script for learning more about web scraping. So I wanted to do that by my own with integrating any API

Answer (score 0):

That page is NOT pointing to YouTube.  Check out the working code sample below for an idea of what you can do with the YouTube API.

```
# https://medium.com/greyatom/youtube-data-in-python-6147160c5833
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
#from youtube_data import youtube_search


test = youtube_search("Nine Inch Nails")
test.keys()

test['commentCount'][:5]

df = pd.DataFrame(data=test)
df.head()

df1 = df[['title','viewCount','channelTitle','commentCount','likeCount','dislikeCount','tags','favoriteCount','videoId','channelId','categoryId']]
df1.columns = ['Title','viewCount','channelTitle','commentCount','likeCount','dislikeCount','tags','favoriteCount','videoId','channelId','categoryId']
df1.head()


#import numpy as np
#numeric_dtype = ['viewCount','commentCount','likeCount','dislikeCount','favoriteCount']
#for i in numeric_dtype:
#    df1[i] = df[i].astype(int)

NIN = df1[df1['channelTitle']=='Nine Inch Nails']
NIN.head()


NIN = NIN.sort_values(ascending=False,by='viewCount')
plt.bar(range(NIN.shape[0]),NIN['viewCount'])
plt.xticks(range(NIN.shape[0]),NIN['Title'],rotation=90)
plt.ylabel('viewCount in 100 millions')

plt.show()
```